# Is there a simple way to JOIN tables from an SQLite repository?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I am working on a program to manage my personal finances.  I have an SQLite database that is storing all of the data, and I am able to load/save accounts, bills, payments, etc.

What I am looking to do, is load the account name of the associated account based on the `PayeeId` of each `Payment`.  I know how to achieve this using SQL, but my data is set up using repositories.  For example, I load the `Payments` by calling

```
var payments = await _paymentsRepository.LoadAllAsync();
```

And the `LoadAllAsync()` method is in `RepositoryBase` class, and looks like so:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TTable>> LoadAllAsync()
{
    var query = _sqliteService.Conn.Table<TTable>();
    var array = (await query.ToListAsync()).ToArray();

    return array;
}
```

and is declared in the `IPaymentsRepository` interface like so:

```
Task<IEnumerable<Payment>> LoadAllAsync();
```

Each `Payment` object has a `PayeeId` property that links to the `Payee` for that `Payment`.  The `Payment` itself doesn't store any of the other information about the `Payee`, but I would like to be able to load the `PayeeName` property to display with the `Payment` information.  Is there a simple way to do this, or will I have to create a separate `ViewModel` to store the "hybrid" data containing both the `Payment` information as well as the `Payee` information?

**EDIT**

I know I can accomplish this using an extra class, for example `PaymentInfo` or something, and store both the `Payment` and `Payee` data, then access it like this: `PaymentInfo.Payment.PaymentAmount` or `PaymentInfo.Payee.PayeeName`, but I would have to load them in two separate queries.  While this is certainly possible, I am hoping for a solution that can be accomplished in one query, which is why I am looking at using a `JOIN`.  If I need to, I will just use LINQ, but my question is whether or not this is possible using the repository setup that I currently have.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the repository code.  I have tried to only include the relevant pieces.  Each table has its own repository.  Here is the signature of the `PaymentsRepository`:

```
public class PaymentsRepository : RepositoryBase<Payment, int>, IPaymentsRepository
{
}
```

The `RepositoryBase<>` looks like this:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TTable, TKey> : IRepository<TTable, TKey>
       where TTable : IKeyedTable<TKey>, new()
{
    protected readonly ISqliteService SqliteService;

    protected RepositoryBase(ISqliteService sqlLiteService)
    {
        SqliteService = sqlLiteService;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TTable>> LoadAllAsync()
    {
        var query = SqliteService.Conn.Table<TTable>();
        var array = (await query.ToListAsync()).ToArray();

        return array;
    }
    ......
}
```

The `IRepository` interface:

```
interface IRepository<TTable, in TKey>
 where TTable : IKeyedTable<TKey>, new()
{
    Task<TTable> LoadByIdAsync(TKey id);
    Task<IEnumerable<TTable>> LoadAllAsync();
    Task InsertAsync(TTable item);
    Task UpdateAsync(TTable item);
    Task DeleteAsync(TTable item);
    AsyncTableQuery<TTable> Query();
}
```

And the `ISqliteService`:

```
public interface ISqliteService
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection Conn { get; }
    Task<object> ClearLocalDb();
    void Reconnect();
}
```

Everything is ultimately queried against that `SQLiteAsyncConnection` property, using the built-in SQLite methods.  For example, in the `LoadAllAsync()` function, `var query = _sqliteService.Conn.Table<TTable>();` uses this:

```
public AsyncTableQuery<T> Table<T> ()
    where T : new ()
{
    //
    // This isn't async as the underlying connection doesn't go out to the database
    // until the query is performed. The Async methods are on the query iteself.
    //
    var conn = GetConnection ();
    return new AsyncTableQuery<T> (conn.Table<T> ());
}
```

which is located in `SQLiteAsync.cs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out a way to directly query two different tables using LINQ, but I got things working with a "hybrid" class.  I just created a `PaymentInfo` class that has a `Payment` property and a `Payee` property, which point to the relevant data.  I added a method to my `PaymentsRepository` that looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PaymentInfo>> LoadAllPaymentInfoAsync()
{
    var payments = await SqliteService.Conn.Table<Payment>().ToListAsync();
    var payees = await SqliteService.Conn.Table<Payee>().ToListAsync();

    var query = from p1 in payments
        join p2 in payees on p1.PayeeId equals p2.Id
        select new PaymentInfo() {Payment = p1, Payee = p2};

    return query;
}
```

I am sure that this is not necessarily the best way to accomplish this, but I thought I would share it here in case anyone comes across this page looking to do what I did.

Comment: what if I've got 500K+ rows on each table? it's terrible idea to load all data and then join them

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get `IQueryable<Payment>` and `IQueryable<Payee>`, join them in LINQ, and then call .ToArray() on the result.

It will build up the query and perform it only when you actually access the data (in this case, on the ToArray() call). *I believe* this should generate a single query.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to get an `IQueryable<>` from the code provided in the question?  I was hoping for something like this: `IQueryable<Payment> payments = SqliteService.Conn.Table<Payment>();` but I get `Cannot convert source type 'SQLite.AsyncTableQuery<MyMoney.Models.Payment>' to target type `'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyMoney.Models.Payment>'

Comment: I have added the relevant repository code.  If you need me to add something else, let me know.